# Drop Down Checkbox not selected while Dynamically Data Binded

Tags: angular, checkbox, multi-select

I need to bind the drop down data dynamically from db and also to select the checkbox
Html file

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="GridOptions" [texts]="myTexts" [settings]="mySettings" [(ngModel)]="GridDataModel"> </ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Ts file

```
GridOptions: IMultiSelectOption[]
GridDataModel : any[];
 ngOnInit() {
  --db service call
GridDataOptions:any[];
 for (let item of DBdatal) {
            var Arr = new Array({ 'id': item.Id, 'name': item.Name });
            GridDataOptions.push(Arr[0]);
        }
GridOptions = GridDataOptions
GridDataModel = [1, 2];

}
```

the checkbox is not selecting based on GridDataModel value.

Answer (score 0):

`GridDataModel` in

```
[(ngModel)]="GridDataModel"
```

needs to reference the selected value, not an array of values.

In code

```
selectedItem = this.GridDataModel[0];
```

in template

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
```